# Not able to retrieve session object in KIE stateful session in Drools rules file

Tags: drools, kie

In Drools rules file (drt) ,I'm storing the productId and Customer name in session . I want to apply discount only if for that particular customer and product ,discount wasn't applied already

Format of the Template file (Excel)

```
ProductID     Quatntity       Discount     
Item_1           10            15    
Item_2           20            20
```

Below is the drt file

```
 template header
    ProductId
    Quantity
    Discount

    package com.main.discount;

dialect "java"


import java.util.Random;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import com.main.discount.Customer;

declare Discount
    lCurrentTime: long
    lCustomerName: String
    lProductId: String
    lExist: boolean
    @timestamp(currentTime)
end

function Discount addDiscount(String productId,String customerName) {
    Discount newRecord = new Discount();
    newRecord.setLCustomerName(customerName);
    newRecord.setLProductId(productId);
    newRecord.setLCurrentTime(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    newRecord.setLExist(true);   
    return newRecord;
}

template "OperationalMeasurement"

rule "Apply_Discount_@{row.rowNumber}"
no-loop
lock-on-active
salience 400
when
  $c: Customer(productId == "@{ProductId}" ,$productId: productId && quantity >= "@{Quantity}" , $quantity: quantity, $customer: CustomerName)
  not (Discount(lProductId == $productId, lCustomerName == $customer))
 then   
    $c.setDiscount("@{Discount}");
    Discount addCondition = addDiscount($productId,$customer);
    insert(addCondition);
    retract($c);
end

end template
```

Below is the code to call Initiate the Drools Kie session

```
  KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
KieSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeSessionConfiguration();
sessionConfig.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get( ClockType.PSEUDO_CLOCK.getId() ) );
try {
    loadRuleTemplate(DATA_FILE, RULE_TEMPLATE_FILE, "Discount", 2, 1);
} catch (IOException errorMsg) {
    log.error(errorMsg.getMessage());       }
InternalKnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
kbase.addPackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());       
KieSession kieSession =  kbase.newKieSession(sessionConfig, null);
sessionClock = ksession.getSessionClock();
ksession.insert(Customer);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

But everytime, not condition is ignored, eventhough record exist for customer and product , it still applies discount, Looks like I'm not able to retrieve Discount object from session.
I'm using Stateful session.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you are having is related to the use of the `lock-on-active` attribute in your rule. The `lock-on-active` is nice to avoid infinite loops, but it comes with a cost: no new activations of that rule can happen by insertion or modifications of facts during the call of `fireAllRules()`.

You can get a better explanation of the `lock-on-active` attibute (and some ways to avoid having to use it) in this [blog post](https://ilesteban.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/about-drools-and-infinite-execution-loops/).

Hope it helps,

Comment: @Estebal Aliverti, Sorry I missed the insert statement in my code.. I have an insert statement, still it doesnt not part is working, i even printed the values in addDiscount, I see them properly added

Comment: I removed lock-on-active and still issue persist

Comment: Please, include the real code you are using. The code snippet you pasted seems to have  errors. For example, you are using a `lCustomerName` variable in the RHS of your rule that is never declared nor bound. The condition `lCustomerName == CustomerName` is also referencing a `CustomerName` variable that is never bound and when you are calling `addDiscount()` it seems that you are passing the arguments in the wrong order (you pass the product first and the customer second, but the function defines them in the opposite order).

Comment: What puzzles me is that (assuming that you tried removing the `lock-on-active` attribute) you are removing the customer in your rules (using `retract`). That there should immediately cancel the activation of all the other rules. Are these the only rules you have in your session?

Comment: I have other rules, which will remove discount when Quantity is less than required count , basically i'm checking if there's an existing discount for customer and product  "Remove_Discount_@{row.rowNumber}"
salience 300
when
  $c: Customer(productId == "@{ProductId}" ,$productId: productId && quantity < "@{Quantity}" , $quantity: quantity, $customer: CustomerName)
  (Discount(lProductId == $productId, lCustomerName == $customer))
 then   
    $c.setDiscount("@{Discount}");
 Discount addCondition = addDiscount($productId,$customer);
 remove(addCondition);
    retract($c);
end'